# Show error message on the same pop up window where form is created

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I have made a form that is displaying in pop up window now I want to validate that form in such a way that error message should display on the same pop up where form is created and also I want to stop the submit event if **Error Array contain some errors** this is the code I have used so far.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal; font-family: inherit;">
                    After clicking claim this item will be reserved for you and you will 
                    receive an invoice from <?php echo get_the_author(); ?> with 
                    instructions for completing payment.
                </p>


                <?php 
                    if($errArray != '') {
                        foreach ($errArray as $error) {
                ?>
                    <div class="btn btn-danger">
                        <ul>
                        <?php
                            if($error != '') {
                        ?>

                            <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>

                        <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>

                <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="POST">

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class=" col-md-5 control-label h4">Name *</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class="control-label col-md-5 h4">Email *</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class="control-label col-md-5 h4">Shipping Address *</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="shipping_address" id="ship_add" placeholder="Enter your Shipping Address" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class="control-label col-md-5 h4">City *</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter your City" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class="control-label col-md-5 h4">State *</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="Enter your State" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class="control-label col-md-5 h4">Zip *</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Enter your Zip Code" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class="control-label col-md-5 h4">Phone *</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px; padding: 0px;">
                        <lable class="control-label col-md-5 h4">Notes</lable>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" id="notes" name="notes" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Claim" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 2%;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $name = esc_attr($_POST['name']);
    $email = esc_attr($_POST['email']);
    $s_address = esc_attr($_POST['shipping_address']);
    $city = esc_attr($_POST['city']);
    $state = esc_attr($_POST['state']);
    $zip = esc_attr($_POST['zip']);
    $phone = esc_attr($_POST['phone']);
    $notes = esc_attr($_POST['notes']);

    $errArray = [];
    if(empty($name)) {
        echo "Name is required";
        array_push($errArray, 'Name is requried');
    }
    if(empty($email)){
        array_push($errArray, 'Email is required');
    }
    if(empty($s_address)){
        array_push($errArray, 'Shipping Address is required');   
    }
    if(empty($city)){
        array_push($errArray, 'City is required');
    }
    if(empty($state)) {
        array_push($errArray, 'State is required');
    }
    if(empty($zip)) {
        array_push($errArray, 'Post Code is required');
    }
    if(empty($phone)){
        array_push($errArray, 'Phone is required');
    }

    if(empty($errArray)){
        global $woocommerce;
          $address = array(
              'first_name' => $name,
              'email'      => $email,
              'phone'      => $phone,
              'address_1'  => $s_address,
              'city'       => $city,
              'state'      => $state,
              'postcode'   => $zip,
          );
          // Now we create the order
          $order = wc_create_order();
          // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
          $order->add_product( get_product($product_id), 1 ); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
          $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
          //
          $order->calculate_totals();
          $order->update_status("wc-new", 'Imported order', TRUE);



        global $wpdb;

        $table = wp_store_claims;
        $data = array(
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            's_address' => $s_address,
            'city' => $city,
            'state' => $state,
            'zip' => $zip,
            'notes' => $notes,
            'phone' => $phone,
        );

        $success = $wpdb->insert($table, $data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

I am stuck here anyone here who can help me out would be great. Thank you in advance

Comment: it seems you mix up something. Your code doesn't have any front-end validation script. So, it has to be submitted. And after submitting you can recover that modal with error message with small php-js script.

Comment: OK i got it but the main issue is I am stuck I'm not sure how to do it sir, do you have any script to do that it would be a great help

Comment: You can use jQuery validation plugin for that. https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I want validation from server side does jquery validation plugin provide that?

Comment: No, jQuery validation provides frontend validation. If you want server-side validation at frontend, you need to use jQuery AJAX FORM SUBMIT logic.

Comment: OK let me try that

Comment: @Mohsin If you want server side validation then on modal you can only do it by using AJAX on submit as "ElvinHaci" has mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I have solved it by sending Ajax request thank you so much @ElvinHaci